# Can't seem to align text to coffee mug template using GIMP, the mug has two centers (one for each side) and this is causing difficulty

Tags: gimp, alignment

[image]The image is of the mug guide template, I am trying to align text vertically and horizontally centered on each side. Made one layer, eyeballed the center and then duplicated it so I could do same on the other side. I'd like it to be exactly centered, not just eyeballed. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is:

- Make guides that intersect where the center of the text should be (so, one horizontal guide in the middle, and two vertical guides),
- Check that View>Snap to guides is enabled
- Use the Move tool: as soon as you start dragging a layer, the center of the layer will be shown with a small cross, and when that cross is close enough to the guides it will snap to them.

Note that this aligns the **layer** and not the "bounding box" of the text, which is smaller, so, depending on the shape of the text, the vertical centering can be off. You can reduce the layer to the bounding box with Layer>Autocrop layer (but this makes the layer a bitmap, so you may want to make a copy first).

Comment: Most welcome. If it works better mark the answer as accepted.